# MongoDB weird performance in Lookup

Tags: mongodb

I want to make two lookups, every one for a different collection

the first lookup

```js
{ $lookup: { from: 'collectionOne',let: { id: '$_id' }, pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: {  $and: [ {$in: ['$$id', '$users.id']}, {$eq: ['$status', 'success']}]}}},
          { $project: {_id: 1}},
], as: 'ones'}},
```

the second lookup

```js
{ $lookup: { from: 'collectionTwo',let: { id: '$_id' }, pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: {  $and: [ {$in: ['$$id', '$users.id']}, {$eq: ['$status', 'success']}]}}},
          { $project: {_id: 1}},
], as: 'twos'}},
```

- if I add the **first lookup only**, the query time will be **128ms**
- if I add the **second lookup only**, the query time will be **134ms**
- if I add the **both lookups in same aggregate pipeline**, the query time will be **28.6s** which is horrible performance.

Note: all the field status and ids are indexed well and that is why the performance very well when running only one lookup, but running the two lookup are very slow like it is ignoring the indexes.

Thanks

Comment: Indexes are used at the beginning stages (especially the `$match` and `$sort`) of the aggregation only - so, its expected the second lookup is not using any. You may want to see the _query plans_ for each of the queries and analyze whats happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using the new lookup in MongoDB **V5**, it allow us to use regular lookup which is really fast with a pipeline.

```js
{ $lookup: { 
    from: 'collectionOne',
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "users.id",
    pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: {$eq: ['$status', 'success']}}},
          { $project: {_id: 1}},
    ],
    as: 'ones'
}},
{ $lookup: { 
    from: 'collectionTwo',
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "users.id",
    pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: {$eq: ['$status', 'success']}}},
          { $project: {_id: 1}},
    ],
    as: 'twos'
}},
```

the above 2 pipelines took only **141ms** which is a really good performance.

**Note**: this solution will not work on older version of MongoDB

Answer (score 1):

Some information about `$lookup`
(if something isn't true comment below if you can)

1. lookup needs index in the from collection
2. that index can be used in whatever place in the pipeline we are
3. lookup kills the index for the next stages, only for the collection that is on the pipeline.
4. [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)  cant use the index expect in  `$eq, $lt, $lte, $gt, and $gte`

For your case if you have indexes on the from collection they can be used fine, but the problem is the `$expr` with `$in`

Solution can be to do a normal lookup(not pipeline) join on field with an array (its like the query `$in`) and index can be used.

I mean something like

```js
{
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "collectionOne",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "users._id",
    "as": "joinOne"
  }
}
{
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "collectionTwo",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "users._id",
    "as": "joinTwo"
  }
}
match ...
project ...
```

This way if you have indexes on `users._id` it will be used in both lookups. If you test it send some feedback if you can, if it worked faster.

Comment: thanks, I used the regular lookup with pipeline which only supported in MongoDB version 5.

Comment: yes good its the same in perfomance, like normal lookup and you fit in the pipeline also, so its better : )

Answer (score 0):

so a couple things you can try of the top of my head:

- leaving localfield, foreignfield empty results in $lookup trying to match for null. (depending on your mongoDB version, which you did not mention)
- changing up the order of match and lookup should be preferred, because you decrease the amount of items you have to lookup.
- the collections should be in the same collation, or the indexes will not be used.